# how can we pass a class dyanmically to directive element.html()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Iam using angular.js, i tried to show the div with some animation when i clicked on another div and i got the solution but there is a problem in my code

here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n28nnLut/)

**here is my html code**

```
<article ng-app="angularSlideables">

  <h1 slide-toggle="#derp" unique-name="add1">Click here for Hipster Ipsum.</h1>

  <div id="derp" slideable unique-content="add1">
    <p>Bespoke aesthetic Bushwick craft beer. Qui aesthetic butcher, cardigan ex scenester Neutra American Apparel mumblecore.</p>
    <p>Ethical adipisicing before they sold out, sriracha Thundercats cardigan dolor deep v placeat. Flannel tattooed meggings direct trade banh mi tousled sriracha. Portland VHS ut dreamcatcher. Butcher eu irony, Banksy leggings eiusmod Pinterest hashtag
      Etsy asymmetrical lo-fi Helvetica quis incididunt adipisicing. YOLO cliche minim mlkshk dreamcatcher excepteur, Austin McSweeney's.</p>
    <p>Coded @ Kinfolk Studios in Williamsburg, Brooklyn, 2013.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Your fresh artisinal Ipsum will appear above this paragraph. </p>


  <h1 slide-toggle="#derpadd2" unique-name="add2">Click here for Hipster Ipsum.</h1>

  <div id="derpadd2" slideable unique-content="add2">
    <p>Bespoke aesthetic Bushwick craft beer. Qui aesthetic butcher, cardigan ex scenester Neutra American Apparel mumblecore.</p>
    <p>Ethical adipisicing before they sold out, sriracha Thundercats cardigan dolor deep v placeat. Flannel tattooed meggings direct trade banh mi tousled sriracha. Portland VHS ut dreamcatcher. Butcher eu irony, Banksy leggings eiusmod Pinterest hashtag
      Etsy asymmetrical lo-fi Helvetica quis incididunt adipisicing. YOLO cliche minim mlkshk dreamcatcher excepteur, Austin McSweeney's.</p>
    <p>Coded @ Kinfolk Studios in Williamsburg, Brooklyn, 2013.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Your fresh artisinal Ipsum will appear above this paragraph. </p>

</article>
```

**here is my directive code**

```
angular.module('angularSlideables', [])
  .directive('slideable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(element, attr) {
        // wrap tag
        var uniqueContent = attr.uniqueContent;
        console.log(uniqueContent);
        var contents = element.html();
        if (attr.uniqueContent === 'add1') {
          element.html('<div class="slideable_contentadd1" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');
        } else if (attr.uniqueContent === 'add2') {
          element.html('<div class="slideable_contentadd2" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');
        }

        /*
        element.html('<div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');*/


        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          // default properties
          attrs.duration = (!attrs.duration) ? '1s' : attrs.duration;
          attrs.easing = (!attrs.easing) ? 'ease-in-out' : attrs.easing;
          element.css({
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'height': '0px',
            'transitionProperty': 'height',
            'transitionDuration': attrs.duration,
            'transitionTimingFunction': attrs.easing
          });
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('slideToggle', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var target = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggle);
        attrs.expanded = false;
        element.bind('click', function() {

          var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content' + attrs.uniqueName);
          if (!attrs.expanded) {
            content.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
            var y = content.clientHeight;
            content.style.border = 0;
            target.style.height = y + 'px';
          } else {
            target.style.height = '0px';
          }
          attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Above code is working correctly but in my "slidable" directive i used if condition to use class in elem.html() to trigger two different divs, When i clicked on "slide-toggle='#derp'" then "id='drep'" will open and also if i clicked on  "slide-toggle='#derpadd2'" then "id='derpadd2'". My problem is i dont want to use if-condition because if i want 10 divs to open with animation means i have to use if-condition for all the 10 , so i want to pass the dynamic class names to element.html()

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can try to use **ng-class** directive in div class and get uniqueContent name with scope variable.

Comment: can u show me in fiddle @oguzhan00

Comment: could you just do like: `element.html('<div class="slideable_content'+attr.uniqueContent+'" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');` ?   Also it looks like using transclusion would be appropriate in this case.

Comment: thanks it is working @plong0